# C++-11 for a map of heterogeneous objects

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a cache of heterogeneous objects, stored by name. Note that there is no common base class for them. At the creation time I also have to store a Deleter object (since I know the type at that time), so the map looks like this:

```
map<string, pair<void *, Deleter> > data;
```

whenever an object is retrieved (by a templated method), it's cast back to the requested type.
The destructor for the cache simply calls the Deleter and removes the pair from the map. This all works.

It would have been nice, however, if C++11 would let me do something like:

```
map<string, unique_ptr_base> data;
```

where unique_ptr_base would be an (imaginary) base class of all unique_ptr's and its virtual destructor would delete the item. Then I could simply remove the item from the map and not worry about deallocation.

Writing a special class for this purpose is not too hard, but in this case isn't justified, since the present way only takes up one more line, and there isn't much danger of leaking the pointer accidentally. So, is there some feature of the new standard I am overlooking, or should I just leave it as is?

Comment: "I have a cache of heterogeneous objects"  Don't do that.  Either have a cache for each type of object, or create an interface.  Note that the interface does _not_ necessarily have to be inherited by the objects directly.

Comment: This is a library, so I have no control over what type the user may want to use. And while maybe I can create a separate cache for each type, but then I'll have a map<type, Cache> to hold all the caches which is a heterogenous map:)

Comment: If absolutely necessary, use `boost::any`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have stateful deleters, you can pretty much use:

```
std::unique_ptr<void, void (*)(void *)>
```

For example:

```
using any_ptr = std::unique_ptr<void, void (*)(void *)>;

any_ptr p(static_cast<void *>(std::fopen("/dev/null")),
          [](void * x) { std::fclose(static_cast<FILE*>(x)); });
```

Comment: So, if my Create does this:  `template<class T> Create(const string&s ) { data.insert(make_pair(s, make_pair(new T, Deleter<T>()))) }` - what would it look like now?

Comment: @user2557021: Something like `data[s] = any_ptr(new T, [](void * p) { Deleter<T>()(static_cast<T*>(p)); })` I suppose.

Comment: @user2557021: You could make a convenience function template: `templaet <typename T, typename D = Deleter<T>> void any_deleter(void * p) { D()(static_cast<T*>(p)); }` and then use `any_ptr(new T, any_deleter<T>)`.